# jQuery - Display Opposite (Invert Selection) Value of Select Dropdown

Tags: jquery, selectedvalue

I want to display Opposite value of Selected Dropdown list.

If I select "**Team A**" from Batting dropdown, Then the **bowling team should be "*Team B*"** and vice versa.

### HTML

```
Batting: 
<select class="battingTeam">
  <option>-- Select Team --</option>
  <option>Team A</option>
  <option>Team B</option>
</select>

<div id="bowlingTeam"></div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".battingTeam").change(function(){
        $("#bowlingTeam").html( 'Bowling:' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent);
     });                      
});
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/24427kda/)

Comment: This kind things you need http://jsfiddle.net/24427kda/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".battingTeam").change(function(){
        var batTeam = $(this).val();
        var bowlTeam = ( batTeam == "Team B" )?"Team A":"Team B";
        $('#bowlingTeam').html("Bowling:" +bowlTeam );
    });
});
```

Check Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hoja/24427kda/1/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".battingTeam").change(function () {
        var value = (this.selectedIndex == 0) ? 0 : (this.selectedIndex == 1) ? 2 : 1;
        (value == 0) ? $("#bowlingTeam").hide() : $("#bowlingTeam").show().html('Bowling:' + this.options[value].textContent);

    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/24427kda/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the options that are `teams` then you don't need to know the specific values

```
<option class="team">Team A</option>
<option  class="team">Team B</option>
```

JS

```
 $(".battingTeam").change(function () {       
    $("#bowlingTeam").html('Bowling:' + $(this).find('.team:not(:selected)').text());
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/24427kda/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: If i choose  option 0 (Select Team) ,it will display 2 team